# Filtering Metadata Keywords from results by 'GetListUsedKeywords()' method

Tags: 2011

I want to fetch all the keywords used in the component content not in the metadata. 
I am using `GetListUsedKeywords()` method to get the keywords of the components. I have written a code like below:

```
XDocument document = null;
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(compCurrent.GetListUsedKeywords().OuterXml);//ListColumnFilter.XMLListExtended).Replace("tcm:Item", "tcmItem"));
```

I am getting the result like below in document variable,

```
<tcm:ListUsedItems xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
  <tcmItem ID="tcm:89-43995-1024" Title="Environment" Type="1024" OrgItemID="tcm:89-6332-512" Path="\120 Rolls-Royce.com Schemas\Sustainability" Icon="T1024L0P0" Publication="120 Rolls-Royce.com Schemas" />
  <tcmItem ID="tcm:89-43996-1024" Title="Communities" Type="1024" OrgItemID="tcm:89-6332-512" Path="\120 Rolls-Royce.com Schemas\Sustainability" Icon="T1024L0P0" Publication="120 Rolls-Royce.com Schemas" />
  <tcmItem ID="tcm:89-48010-1024" Title="Case Study" Type="1024" OrgItemID="tcm:89-7063-512" Path="\120 Rolls-Royce.com Schemas\Functionality Type" Icon="T1024L0P0" Publication="120 Rolls-Royce.com Schemas" />
</tcm:ListUsedItems>
```

As in this result, The method `GetListUSedKeywords()` brings all the keywords(in content as well as metadata). I do not want element with Title "Case Study" , as it belongs to metadata of the component.

How can I filter and fetch only the keywords of the component content and not metadata?

is it possible by `GetListUsedKeywords(filter)` by passing filter to the function?

pls help.

Comment: Can you give some more detail about the Component and its Schema, from your list I would say that all three of those Keywords are used by the Component.

Comment: 1. do you mean "Group" by category in the sentence(because it is actually not in a group of other two elements) ? 2. what do you mean by "Folder" in the sentence (last element in xml, which is coming from the other folder). I guess you mean "Category" here, right?

Comment: @SaurabhGangwar, Yes it is a type of Category.

Comment: against which condition(logic) you want to filter out the last Element?

Comment: @saurab,@Bart - The actual problem is that the case study is the keyword which is in the metadata of the component. So the method .GetListUSedKeywords brings all the keywords. My component uses 2 keywords and third keyword (case study)which is in the metadata of the component is also coming. How can i filter and fetch only the keywords of the component and not metadata.

Comment: Which context you are running the code?

Comment: We are firing OnPagePublishPost event. During this event execution, we are generating xml file, having details of some component fields. At that time, we need all categories from the path '\120 Rolls-Royce.com Schemas\Sustainability' only but we also get the unexpected keyword from '\120 Rolls-Royce.com Schemas\Functionality Type', as you can see in xml in question.

Comment: I doubt, there is one overloaded method of GetListUsedKeywords(filter), but do not have any idea, what value should be passed in filter parameter or how to use this Filter type exactly. If any idea then pls suggest.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13730/discussion-between-saurabh-gangwar-and-urvesh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out keywords used in content data, you need to read the schema of the component  and go through all the content fields.

if field is using a category, add it to a collection object (`string[] CatIDs` in the code below). and use it for filtering the xml results.

you can try the below code:

```
                            string[] CatIDs; // collection of the categories used in conent fields
                            XElement xmlData;
                            xmlData = document.Root;
                            XNamespace ns = xmlData.GetDefaultNamespace();
                            string fieldName = "tcmItem";

//filtering out keywords form the category tcm:89-7063-512
                            var results = xmlData.Descendants(ns + fieldName).Where(i => CatIDs.Contains( i.Attribute("OrgItemID").Value));
```

the variable results shall contain the filtered elements.

PS: I have not run this code, adjustments could be needed